# How to remove comma at end of last line in an array

Tags: bash, sed

I am using `sed '$s/,$//'` to try to remove the comma at the end of the final line of an array, which has the opening and closing brackets on their lines (as shown below). This command `sed '$s/,$//'` isn't working as intended.

If I do `sed '$s/]$//'` it will remove the closing array bracket, so I know I'm kind of on the right track....

```
[
{"foo":"foofoo","fuzz":["fee, fi, fo, fum"]},
{"bar":"barbar","fuzz":["blah", "blah"]},
]
```

this is for a bash script. please do not provide answer that uses perl.

Comment: Is this supposed to be valid JSON? The thing producing it should be fixed to stop adding the incorrect comma.

Comment: @chepner yes, it is. not sure how to do that (subject for another question...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no comma in last line so `'$s/,$//'` will not work for `sed`.

Instead of `sed` you can use `awk`:

```
awk '$1 == "]"{sub(/,$/, "", s)} NR>1{print s} {s=$0} END{print s}' file
[
{"foo":"foofoo","fuzz":["fee, fi, fo, fum"]},
{"bar":"barbar","fuzz":["blah", "blah"]}
]
```

OR you can use this `perl` command:

```
perl -0pe 's/,(\s\])/$1/' file
[
{"foo":"foofoo","fuzz":["fee, fi, fo, fum"]},
{"bar":"barbar","fuzz":["blah", "blah"]}
]
```

Comment: hi, perl is not an option here. Thank you though. Anyway to do this with bash, sed, awk? there's no perl tag to the question (I assumed that was sufficient to communicate that I am not looking for an answer in perl) but if not, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain why it's necessary to do all this `s{print s} {s=$0}`  (i.e. use the `s` variable three times in that part of the command) with `s` (the string)?

Comment: Changed it little bit for clarity. `NR>1{print s}` prints variable `s`only for 2nd record onwards. For 1st record we are storing `$0` in `s`. So printing starts from 2nd record onwards and that's the reason we print in `END` block also.

Comment: If the input is completely regular, you could put the `sub` in the `END` block as well.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;s/,(\n])/\1/;P;D' file
```

Read two lines and remove a `,` when it occurs before a `]` at the junction them.

Answer (score 0):

While you already have an answer using `awk`, just be aware the same thing can be accomplished using the *built-ins* that bash provides:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -r "$1" ] || {  ## validate filename given as argument
    printf "error: file not readable. usage: %s filename\n" "${0##*/}"
    exit 1
}

while read -r line; do 

    [ -z "$last" ] && { last="$line"; continue; } ## if last not set, continue

    if [ "$line" == "]" ]; then  ## if line "]", check last
        [ ${last:(-1)} == ',' ] && last=${last%,}  ## check for & remove comma
    fi

    [ -z "$last" ] || echo $last  ## echo if $last set
    last="$line"

done <"$1"
echo $last  ## print final line

exit 0
```

**Output**

```
$ bash stripcomma.sh dat/endcomma.txt
[
{"foo":"foofoo","fuzz":["fee, fi, fo, fum"]},
{"bar":"barbar","fuzz":["blah", "blah"]}
]
```

Comment: This removes trailing comma from each line but intent is to remove trailing `,` only when next line is `]`.

Comment: Screwed that one up didn't I. I'll yank the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk 'NR>2{sub(/,$/,"")}1' file
[
{"foo":"foofoo","fuzz":["fee, fi, fo, fum"]},
{"bar":"barbar","fuzz":["blah", "blah"]}
]
```

Comment: This will remove commas from more lines than the last if there are more than two entries in the array.